# I need to access a Tuple in Python

Tags: python, list, tuples

I was using get request to get some data by this code

```
at = airtable.Airtable('BASE_ID', 'API_KEY')
airtable_data = at.get('Table 3')
print(airtable_data)
```

and the results was

```
OrderedDict([('records', [OrderedDict([('id', 'rec3qP7SjyowO'), ('fields',OrderedDict([('User', 'User'), ('Text', 'TEST'), ('Date', '2020-01-15T13:09:03.000Z')])), ('createdTime', '2020-01-15T13:09:09.000Z')]), OrderedDict([('id', 'recOUVoNXHak'), ('fields', OrderedDict([('User', 'user'), ('Text', 'TEST'), ('Date', '2020-01-15T13:05:43.000Z')])), ('createdTime', '2020-01-15T13:08:55.000Z')])])])
```

then I used

```
airtable_list = (list(airtable_data))
print(airtable_list[0])
```

the results was 
records 
only and I can't find a way to extract the rest of the data

Comment: Don't convert it to a list, it will result in a list of the keys only. The output fornat of an OrderedDict is a bit confusing. Just  access the keys directly.

Comment: @KlausD. if I don't convert  it I get "KeyError: 1' so I can't access it

Comment: The keys are not integers, they are the left items of the tuples.

Comment: @KlausD. So how could I access it?

Comment: added the logic to access the entries. This is one of the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that when you pass that `OrderdDict` through `List`, it gives you value of `key` which is `records`.

To display the proper data, you can use below logic.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
airtable_data = OrderedDict([('records', [OrderedDict([('id', 'rec3qP7SjyowO'), ('fields',OrderedDict([('User', 'User'), ('Text', 'TEST'), ('Date', '2020-01-15T13:09:03.000Z')])), ('createdTime', '2020-01-15T13:09:09.000Z')]), OrderedDict([('id', 'recOUVoNXHak'), ('fields', OrderedDict([('User', 'user'), ('Text', 'TEST'), ('Date', '2020-01-15T13:05:43.000Z')])), ('createdTime', '2020-01-15T13:08:55.000Z')])])])

for k,v in airtable_data.items():
    i = 0
    for data in v:
        i += 1
        for k1, v1 in data.items():
            print(k1,'---->', v1)
        print('Data displayed for item number ', i)
        print('----------------------------------------------------')
        print(' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

since your variable `airtable_data` is `OrderedDict` type you can get the rest of the data by accessing the value for the key `records`:

```
my_data = airtable_data['records']
```